# How to get the selected row id of a GridPanel

Tags: selecteditem, ext.net, gridpanel

I have a GridPanel named GridPanel1 and a button to remove the selected row of the GridPanel,
I want to get the selected row id by clicking a ext button and send the id to a directMethod.
My code is:

```
var removeEmployee = function () {
    // CompanyZ.Delete(id); // Here I need the GridPanel selected row id
    console.log(mygrid);
}
```

Please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].getId()
```